# Proving the existence of fixed point $\alpha \in [-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Can anyone help me with the following problem: I don't have the slightest idea on where to start:

Consider a function $g$ which is continuous on the compact interval $[-1,1]$ such that: $g(-1)=0$, $g(0)=1$ and $g(1)=-1$. We need to show that there exists $\alpha \in [-1,1]$ such that $g(g(\alpha))=\alpha$.

Comment: Hint: work out $g(g(x))$ at $x=-1, 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$g(g(1))-1=g(-1)-1=-1$

$g(g(-1))+1=g(0)+1=2$

Since $g$ is continuous, so is $g(g(x))-x$, and this function takes $-1$ at $1$ and $2$ at $-1$. So, there exists a point in between such that $g(g(\alpha))-\alpha=0$

Answer (score 1):

Try using what you're given about the domain and range of the function, and applying the intermediate value theorem.